# How Can I Force .NET (C#) to Use the non-generic overload of a method?

Tags: c#, c++, generics

There's a method in the .NET Framework that has both generic and a non-generic version/overload.  I want to force the compiler to generate my code using the non-generic version even if it can resolve the generic type at build time.

The specific method I want to use is `Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` which, as of .NET 4.5.1, has a generic overload. I want to use the original one (non-generic).

Also, if you could provide the solution (if any) in C++/CLI, it'd be much appreciated.

UPDATE: There reason for this is that, if my program is ran in a computer that does not have .NET 4.5.1, my program will crash.

Comment: Do not worry about it... Why? Look at the implementation of [GetFunctionPointerForDelegate<TDelegate>](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#7b9d71d9432f3274)

Comment: Just to include what @elgonzo linked to here, this is the generic method body: `return GetFunctionPointerForDelegate((Delegate)(object)d);`

Comment: Thanks, but actually my problem is that, if my program gets run in a system that has pre-4.5.1 .NET Framework, it will crash.

Comment: @Anzurio, set the build target of your project to a .NET version prior to 4.5.1 - if your project needs to run on .NET 3.5, set the build target framework of your project to .NET 3.5...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be clear from the source code snippet posted by @elgonzo that the generic version is calling the non-generic version, otherwise you would have infinite recursion.

Therefore, you too can call the non-generic version.  The trick is making the non-generic version a perfect match.

C#:

```
Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate( (Delegate)(object) mydel );
```

C++/CLI:

```
Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate( dynamic_cast<Delegate^>(safe_cast<Object^>(mydel)) );
```

Answer (score 2):

It does not really matter whether you use the generic or the non-generic variant of the *Marshall.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate* method.

The only thing *Marshall.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate<TDelegate>(...)* does is calling the non-generic `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(...)` method.

As can be seen in the .NET framework [reference source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/7b9d71d9432f3274.html), the implementation of *GetFunctionPointerForDelegate<TDelegate>* is just:

```
public static IntPtr GetFunctionPointerForDelegate<TDelegate>(TDelegate d)
{
    return GetFunctionPointerForDelegate((Delegate)(object)d);
}
```

Regarding your update

> UPDATE: There reason for this is that, if my program is ran in a computer that does not > have .NET 4.5.1, my program will crash.

Set the target framework of your project to a .NET version prior to 4.5.1 (for example, if your project is required to run on .NET 3.5, then set the target framework of your project to .NET 3.5.)

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned my reasoning.

Comment: This answer contains the correct answer, although the correct answer is not "don't worry about it".

Comment: Unfortunately, the C++/CLI compiler doesn't allow you to specific older framework versions, it always targets the current version of .NET... yeah

Comment: @BenVoigt, it is not true - at least forVS2010 (which i just tested). In VS2010 you can specify the target framework for C++/CLI projects. Not sure whether it is still the same case in VS2013, though. (Changing the target framework for an existing project might be a bit of a PITA, though...)

Comment: @elgonzo: The IDE supports it, but it actually uses multi-targetting and invokes an older copy of the C++/CLI compiler (I presume you have VS2008 or VS2005 installed in parallel?)  Which really is not a good option, seeing all the new C++11 features and bug fixes on newer Visual C++ versions.

Comment: @BenVoigt, i only have VS2010 Pro and VS2013 C# Express installed. Not sure about the C++ multi-targetting compiler thing. However, if one wants to have a C++/CLI project being able to run on an older .NET framework while keeping the project target framework on the newest .NET framework, then he will probably have much fun in making sure that the (framework) assembly references used by the project don't fail when the software is executed on an older .NET framework... (it will really depend on *which* assemblies the project uses...)